# Leaflet: How to fetch geojson from URL and pass it to L.geoJson

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, geojson

I try to load a geojson from an URL and display it in a map with leaflet:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="my_map" style="height: 600px"></div>
<script>
const map = L.map('my_map')
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);
map.setView([37.8, -96], 4);
async function load_shapefile() {
    let url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shawnbot/topogram/master/data/us-states.geojson';
    let shape_obj = await (await fetch(url)).json();
    return shape_obj
}
L.geoJson(load_shapefile()).addTo(map);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I get on the JS Console:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid GeoJSON object.
    at De (GeoJSON.js:221)
    at i.addData (GeoJSON.js:117)
    at initialize (GeoJSON.js:92)
    at new i (Class.js:22)
    at Object.Ke (GeoJSON.js:439)
    at leaflet.html:21
```

If possible, I would like to not use jQuery.
Thanks for any input!

**EDIT: I replaced the url with an actual GeoJSON file, thanks @IvanSanchez!**

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The JSON is not GeoJSON (and is not a shapefile as well), but it looks like it's TopoJSON instead.

Comment: Thank you @IvanSanchez! I replaced the url with a proper GeoJSON. Unfortunately, the problem persists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to extract the geojson and use it later you need to create another function to await the result as the operation is asynchornous:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="my_map" style="height: 600px"></div>
  <script>
    const map = L.map('my_map')
    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);
    map.setView([37.8, -96], 4);

    async function load_shapefile() {
      let url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shawnbot/topogram/master/data/us-states.geojson';
      const response = await fetch(url)
      const shape_obj = await response.json();
      console.log(shape_obj);
      return shape_obj;
    }

    async function main() {
      const json = await load_shapefile();
      L.geoJson(json).addTo(map);
    }

    main();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Otherwise if you do not want to use the geojson instance further use `then` to fetch the data and immediately use them.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="my_map" style="height: 600px"></div>
  <script>
    const map = L.map('my_map')
    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);
    map.setView([37.8, -96], 4);

    let url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shawnbot/topogram/master/data/us-states.geojson';
    const response = fetch(url).then(response => response.json()).then(response => {
      L.geoJson(response).addTo(map);
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

[@kboul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66367039/edit) already points out  how to fix it, but doesn't explain *why it fails* in the first place.

The original code is failing because `async function`s return an instance of `Promise`, and the `L.GeoJSON` constructor expects a static data structure.

So instead of

```js
async function load_shapefile() {
    let url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shawnbot/topogram/master/data/us-states.geojson';
    let shape_obj = await (await fetch(url)).json();
    return shape_obj
}
L.geoJson(load_shapefile()).addTo(map);
```

You can do

```js
load_shapefile().then(function(geojsonData){
    L.geoJson(load_shapefile()).addTo(map);
});
```

And abusing the syntax of `.then()` a bit to pass function references only:

```js
load_shapefile().then(L.geoJson).then(map.addLayer.bind(map));
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="my_map" style="height: 600px"></div>
  <script>
    const map = L.map('my_map')
    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);
    map.setView([37.8, -96], 4);

    async function load_shapefile() {
      let url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shawnbot/topogram/master/data/us-states.geojson';
      const response = await fetch(url)
      const shape_obj = await response.json();
      console.log(shape_obj);
      return shape_obj;
    }

    load_shapefile().then(L.geoJson).then(map.addLayer.bind(map));
    
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```